# What is this "crystal ball" located at a meteorological station?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, instrumentation

I found what looks like a "crystal ball" in a meteorological station in the Vlădeasa mountains (Romania). What is its purpose?

[image]

Comment: It's a high-tech version of the [weather rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_rock)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a [Campbell-Stokes sunshine recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell%E2%80%93Stokes_recorder), used to record the times at which the sun is shining. It acts as a lens, focusing the sunlight onto a piece of card. If the sun is shining, the focused beam will burn a hole through the card at that point.

Here's a closer view of a sunshine recorder in Wendelstein, Bavaria:
[image: Sunshine recorder]
<sup>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heliograph_wendelstein_2002_00a.jpg)</sup>

And here's a used recording card with holes burned through it:
[image: Recording card]
<sup>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sunshine_card_closeup.JPG)</sup>

Comment: But beware of early morning frost on the glass sphere, which may diffuse the focus so that early sunshine is not recorded.